# 12 gauge on 30 amp circuit - after thermostat

Tags: thermostat, heater

I have 2 2500 watt baseboard heaters that I'm planning on running off of a 30a 240v breaker. My question is, because the thermostat is close to the panel, can I run the 10/2 JUST to the thermostat, then run 12/2 to each heater individually?

Comment: Not a pro, but I believe **all** the wire from a breaker needs to be able to carry **all** the current from the breaker.

Comment: Yes.  The wire needs to be able to carry enough current so the breaker trips **before** the wire overheats and starts a fire.   Like wires, breakers are thermal and can take 40 minutes to trip if the overload is slight.  That is by design, they are designed to trip in conditions analgous to the wires overheating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NO. If this electric heat circuit is on a 30A breaker then ALL the wiring on the circuit must be #10cu (or larger). Even if it feeds just one heater.

Comment: Sounds good. Just wanted to save money on the wire.